# What is the best way to get a n*n matrix from user (console)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

is there any pre-implemented function to get an N*N matrix from user through console ?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: No.  Roll your own with `np.fromstring`

Answer (score 0):

There is no native method. 
You can use, for example: 1 matrix row per line using delimiter between numbers in rows. Like this way.

```
matrix = []
DEFAULT_VALUE = 3
DELIMITER = ' '

try:
    N = int(input("Enter N:"))
except:
    print("Parsing error. Default N = 3")
    N = DEFAULT_VALUE

i = 0
while i < N:
    row = input("Enter row %d (cell delimiter: '%s'): " % (i + 1, DELIMITER))
    try:
        parsed_row = list(map(int, row.split(DELIMITER)))
    except:
        print("Conversion to int error. Please repeat")
        continue

    if len(parsed_row) != N:
        print("Please enter exactly %d numbers" % N)
        continue

    matrix.append(parsed_row)
    i += 1

print("Your matrix:")
print("\n".join(map(lambda x: " ".join(map(lambda y: "%5d" % y, x)), matrix)))
```

Answer (score 0):

If your user(s) understands the Python/NumPy syntax, you can just make your program accept valid code as input:

```
import numpy as np
# Input from user.
# Note that surrounding [] are allowed but not necessary
s = '[1,2], [3,4]'
# Convert input to matrix
matrix = np.array(eval(s))
print(matrix)
```

This approach is rather robust as it is. For example, the input `'[(1,2), [3,4]]'` results in the same matrix.

To improve the robustness further (now allowing illegal Python syntax), you could use

```
import re, numpy as np
# Input from user
s = '(1 2) (3 4)'
# Convert input to matrix
matrix = np.array(eval(re.sub('\s+', ',', s.strip())))
print(matrix)
```

which now enables spaces to be used (as well as commas, as before) to separate the matrix elements.

Answer (score 0):

Well there is multiple way to answer this ...

1. Well if matrix is n*n that means with first input line you know number of input lines (and no, it's impossible for input() to not end with key enter is pressed). So you need something like this:

   ```
   arr = []
   arr.append(input().split())
   for x in range(len(arr[0]) - 1):
       arr.append(input().split())
   ```

   I used range(len(arr[0]) - 1) so it inputs rest of lines (because matrix width and height is same and one first line is already read from input).

   Also I used .split() without " " as parameter because it's default parameter.

2.or you can use this ...

```
>>> import math
>>> line = ' '.join(map(str, range(4*4))) # Take input from user
    '0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15'
>>> items = map(int, line.split()) # convert str to int
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
>>> n = int(math.sqrt(len(items))) # len(items) should be n**2
    4
>>> matrix = [ items[i*n:(i+1)*n] for i in range(n) ]
    [[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14, 15]]
```

3.

Try something like this instead of setting the matrix one by one using existing list(s):

```
# take input from user in one row
nn_matrix = raw_input().split()
total_cells =  len(nn_matrix)
# calculate 'n'
row_cells = int(total_cells**0.5)
# calculate rows
matrix = [nn_matrix[i:i+row_cells] for i in xrange(0, total_cells, row_cells)]
```

Example:

```
>>> nn_matrix = raw_input().split()
    1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
>>> total_cells =  len(nn_matrix)
>>> row_cells = int(total_cells**0.5)
>>> matrix = [nn_matrix[i:i+row_cells] for i in xrange(0, total_cells, row_cells)]
>>> matrix
   [['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6'], ['7', '8', '9']]
```

Answer (score 0):

The closest to a numpy builtin is the `np.matrix` functon.  As a MATLAB clone it accepts, among other things, a string:

```
In [1550]: np.matrix('1 2;3 4')
Out[1550]: 
matrix([[1, 2],
        [3, 4]])
```

The result is `matrix` subclass, so I recommend converting it to an array immediately:

```
In [1551]: np.matrix('1 2;3 4').A
Out[1551]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
```

And married with `input`:

```
In [1552]: np.matrix(input('>')).A
>1 2 3; 4 5 6
Out[1552]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

This does not enforce squareness.  You have to provide that test.

This should be fine for small toy inputs.  But for anything big, I'd recommend taking input from a file, which the user can edit before hand.

`np.loadtxt` and `np.genfromtxt` are good tools for creating an array from a csv formatted file.  There are lots of questions about using those.

The basic array definition is with a list of lists:

```
alist = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
arr = np.array(alist)
```

So anything that can build such a list from user input can work.  For example you could accept lines of 'numbers'

```
In [1558]: alist = ['1 2 3'.split(),'4 5 6'.split()]
In [1559]: alist
Out[1559]: [['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6']]
```

Making array from this list results in a string dtype

```
In [1560]: np.array(alist)
Out[1560]: 
array([['1', '2', '3'],
       ['4', '5', '6']], 
      dtype='<U1')
```

but you can specify `dtype` (as int or float) and `array` will try to convert the strings.  You could also convert the strings to numbers right after input.

```
In [1561]: np.array(alist, dtype=int)
Out[1561]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

You could accept `[]` as well, but those are more of a pain to deal with.